# jenkins ssh run remote python script

Tags: python, jenkins, ssh

in my jenkins job i scp script setup.py to remote server. How run script with parameter?
I try ssh -tt user@host "stty rows 50 cols 132 && cd install && python setup.py --batch" No luck, parameter --batch no processed.
How run remote python script with parameter in jenkins and see output in log?